# Find a number in a list of similar numbers by x%

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, .net-core

I have the the following list of numbers in which I need to find a number which meets the 5% difference between min and max value of the closest matched numbers and calculate its average.

**Input List**

[2500, 2510, 7000, 7500, 1000, 1200, 2460]

**Expected Output**

2500+2510+2460  / 3 = **2490**

Here min 2460, max 2510 and difference is 50 which is lesser than 5% of 2460 i.e 123

```
  var numbers = new int[]{ 2500, 2510, 7000, 7500, 1000, 1200, 2460};
  var orderedNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

  var numbersToConsider = ???? //2500, 2510, 2460 that they are similar with in 5% range
```

I stuck to find the numbers here.

I need to find a similar to each other. Basically the numbers are  monthly loan payment and some other expenses. The loan payment can vary by x% mostly less than 5%. Now I need to figure out those loan payments from the list and take an average

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Why order the numbers?

Comment: How do we find those numbers 2500, 2510, 2460 that they are with in 5% range

Comment: @MrSmith42 ordering may be helpful to find them. Basically I need to calculate distance between two numbers and apply my condition. But I need to iterate all items I guess so

Comment: You seem to search clusters within your data, whose similarity is 95%, don´t you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes I need to find a similar to each other. Basically the numbers are  monthly loan payment with some expenses. The loan payment can vary by x% mostly less than 5%. Now I need to figure out those loan payments from the list and take an average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the "close" numbers in this way:

```
const int maxPercentage = 5;
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{2500, 2510, 7000, 7000, 7500, 1000, 1200, 2460};
List<List<int>> closeNumbers = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (int i in numbers.OrderBy(i => i))
{
    if(closeNumbers.Count == 0)
    {
        closeNumbers.Add(new List<int> {i});
        continue;
    }

    List<int> lastCloseNumbers = closeNumbers.Last();
    int maxDistance = (int)(lastCloseNumbers.Average() / 100.0 * maxPercentage);
    if(i - lastCloseNumbers.Last() <= maxDistance)
        lastCloseNumbers.Add(i);
    else
        closeNumbers.Add(new List<int> {i});
}
```

What you want to do with them is not so clear, but i think this gives you all you need.

Result:

```
1000 
 
1200  

2460 
2500 
2510 

7000 
7000 

7500
```

Comment: It helps me really :) How we get 7000 & 7500 in the list of closeNumbers? They are not 5% difference. I updated my use case in question for more clarity on what I am trying to achieve :)

Comment: @Developer: the two last values sum is 14500 and 5% is 725, but their difference is 500

Comment: I am not looking for sum of 5% of two values. Its basically the 5% difference between min and max value in each list

Comment: 7500-7000 = 500 , 5 % of min value 7000 is 350 but the difference is 500. So we need to ignore

Comment: @Developer: i thought you wanted to check for 5% of the sum in the list, so include the new number in that calculation. I have edited the answer.

Comment: You saved my day! I was trying this logic for last 2 days and stuck :) I accept this as an answer

Comment: I get ´7000, 7000, 7500´ for input ´2500, 2510, 7000, 7000, 7500, 1000, 1200, 2460´ instead ´7000, 7000´ .

Comment: @Developer: maybe you want 5% of the average instead of the sum. Edited it

Answer (score 0):

1. calculate average `avg`
2. calculate `min=avg-5%`
3. calculate `max=avg+5%`
4. iterate your values and output all that are between `min` and `max`